# How to load formatter.nvim with lazy.nvim?

Tags: neovim, formatting, lazyvim

I am trying to load [formatter.nvim](https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim) but I get this error:

```
Lua Diagnostics undefined field 'setup'
```

[image]

What is the path for the logs?

This is my full configuration:

```lua
return {
    'mhartington/formatter.nvim',
    config = function()
        -- Utilities for creating configurations
        local util = require "formatter.util"

        -- Provides the Format, FormatWrite, FormatLock, and FormatWriteLock commands
        require("formatter").setup({
            -- Enable or disable logging
            logging = true,
            -- Set the log level
            log_level = vim.log.levels.DEBUG,
            -- All formatter configurations are opt-in
            filetype = {
                lua = {
                    require("formatter.filetypes.lua").stylua,
                    function()
                        return {
                            exe = "stylua",
                            args = {
                                "--column-width",
                                "120",
                                "--indent-type",
                                "Spaces",
                                "--indent-width",
                                "2",
                                "--search-parent-directories",
                                "--stdin-filepath",
                                util.escape_path(util.get_current_buffer_file_path()),
                                "--",
                                "-",
                            },
                            stdin = true,
                        }
                    end
                },
                ["*"] = {
                    require("formatter.filetypes.any").remove_trailing_whitespace,
                    function()
                        vim.lsp.buf.format({ async = true })
                    end,
                }
            }
        })
    end
}
```

But not working, after I call `:Format`, the code is not formatted.

Comment: Have you tried using `:FormatWrite`?

Answer (score 0):

You normally have to specify `cmd = { "Format", "FormatWhatever" }` on the same level as `config`.

This is the lazy loading trigger. Currently it is set to lazy, but there is no event or something to trigger the loading of the plugin.
You can also go with `lazy=false` to disable lazy loading. Check some examples maybe in lazyvim how Folke is doing it.

Besides that your setup function looks fine tho.